# java.sql.SQLException: Before / after start of result set

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, resultset

I'm having an issue with getting my program to read information from a database. I'd like it to basically print out a table with the extracted information (and the tutorial I followed does exactly that). Unfortunately after pouring over my code and the tutorials I can find no difference. Eventually I want to be able to pull information from the data base and allow the user to edit this information.

Here is my code:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Main {
//Driver and connection URL.
private String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/employees"; 

//DB Credentials.
private static String password = "password";
private static String username = "root";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null; 

        try {
            //Register JDBC Driver.
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString,      username, password);
            System.out.println("Connected to database.");


            statement =    connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,  ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);


            resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * from employees");  

            //process query results.
            ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
            int numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
            System.out.println("Emloyees table of Employees DB");

            for (int i=1; i<=numberOfColumns; i++){
                System.out.printf("%-10s\t", resultSet.getObject(i));    //Return the value of a given object as a java object.
            }
            System.out.println();

            //Initial cursor is before first row. 
            while(resultSet.next()){ //move cursor forward one row.
                for (int i=1; i<=numberOfColumns; i++){
                    System.out.printf("%-10s\t", metaData.getColumnName(i));
                }
            }
            System.out.println();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try{
                connection.close();
                statement.close();
                resultSet.close();
            }
                catch(SQLException se){
                    se.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        System.out.println("Great! Everything works!");
        }

}
```

Here is my what happens when I run the program:

```
Fri Aug 12 19:49:55 EDT 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without    server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.

Connected to database.
Emloyees table of Employees DB
java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:963)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:896)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:885)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:790)
at com.mysql.jdbc.UpdatableResultSet.checkRowPos(UpdatableResultSet.java:214)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getObject(ResultSetImpl.java:4432)
at Main.main(Main.java:38)
Great! Everything works!
```

Worth noting: It is connecting to the database and if I swap my for loop with my while loop it will print off the name of each column several times and the java.sql.SQLException will take place after the start of the result set instead of before.

Answer (score 2):

Your code makes no sense. You can't call `ResultSet.getObject()` unless `next()` has returned true, and you don't need to call `ResultSet.next()` in a loop just to print out the column names. They don't change per row.

It is also to be presumed that you want to print the column names before the data.

The loop that prints the column names should be where the loop that prints the `getObject()` values is, and *vice versa.*